# Excerpt from Mahabharata?

Tags: identification-request

> The one who is patient is the lord of all he surveys

Does anyone know this quotation from Mahabharatha or any other epic? What is the source of this excerpt ?

What does it mean ?

Comment: Where did you hear it?

Comment: Give the Sanskrita lines.

Comment: Patience means that you are stopping for time or allegorically you make the time stop on that event. When time stops you have all the time in the world to survey.

Answer (score 2):

Well couldn't find exactly same but something that is close to it. First read this:

**[SB 11.21.27](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/21/27)**

> Lord Kṛṣṇa states in Bhagavad-gītā (15.15), vedaiś ca sarvair aham eva
>   vedyaḥ: all Vedic knowledge is actually meant to lead one to pure love
>   of Godhead. Lord Kṛṣṇa is certainly the Absolute Truth, and to love
>   Him is the ultimate purpose of our existence. **The Vedic knowledge
>   patiently tries to bring the conditioned soul to this perfection of
>   pure Kṛṣṇa consciousness**.

**[SB 4.29.5](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/29/5)**

> He thinks, “I am the monarch of all I survey.” This is ignorance.
>   Janasya moho ’yam ahaṁ mameti. This is called illusion. Nothing
>   belongs to the living entity, but he claims that everything belongs to
>   him. When the mirror of intelligence is polished, the real activities
>   of the living entity begin. This means that when a person comes to the
>   platform of Kṛṣṇa consciousness, his real intelligence acts. At that
>   time he knows that everything belongs to Kṛṣṇa and nothing belongs to
>   him. **As long as one thinks that everything belongs to him, he is in
>   material consciousness, and when he knows perfectly that everything
>   belongs to Kṛṣṇa, he is in Kṛṣṇa consciousness.**

**[CC Madhya 24.174](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/24/174)**

> ‘ātmā’-śabde ‘dhṛti’ kahe, — dhairye yei rame dhairyavanta eva hañā
>   karaya bhajane
>
> “Another meaning of ‘ātmā’ is dhṛti, or endurance. A person who
>   endeavors with endurance is ātmārāma. With endurance, such a person
>   engages in devotional service.

**[SB 1.14.4](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/14/4)**

> In the conditioned state the living being is not satisfied even if he
>   actually **becomes the lord of all that he surveys**, which he never
>   becomes.

So the crux is that a living being can not become the lord of all that he surveys, because everything belongs to Kṛṣṇa and nothing belongs to him. But vedic knowledge patiently tries to bring the conditioned soul to this perfection of pure Kṛṣṇa consciousness.